# How do I shorten a namespace within a class?

Tags: c++, namespaces, using, global-namespace, namespace-alias

I want to shorten a namespace for use within `MyClass`, for example by `using namespace` or defining an alias:

```
namespace foo = really::loong::name::space;

class MyClass {
private:
    foo::FooClass f;
// ...
};
```

However, this pollutes the global namespace and risks affecting code elsewhere. I could wrap the above code within a name space, but I'm quite happy with the name `MyClass` and I'd rather not have to refer to it as `mynamespace::MyClass`. Is there any way around this?

Comment: *"However, this pollutes the global namespace"* - Why isn't your class itself inside a dedicated namespace? It is strongly advised to do so.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want `MyClass` itself in the global namespace? Then you really need to define it inside the specific namespace, even if it's long and with many nestings.

Comment: It is kinda contradictory to consider `foo` as polluting but `MyClass` somehow not. Also, you can still refer to `MyClass` unqualified *inside* the namespace that it's defined in.

Answer (score 3):

> but I'm quite happy with the name `MyClass` and I'd rather not have to refer to it as `mynamespace::MyClass`.

Put the class in a namespace anyway so it doesn't pollute the global namepsace either. If your users prefer short names, they can add a `using mynamespace::MyClass`.

Comment: I may be worth adding this `using` idea to the linked duplicate Q&A as well. It's not suggested by any of the answers there yet.